# Does GTest has something like Catch2 GENERATE?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, catch2

Catch2 GENERATE looks quite nice and I would like something similar in GTest.

I know about parametrized tests in GTest but I dislike the split from the test body and list of values and the ugly call to GetParam().

Additionally I love the range,take,random feature of GENERATOR in Catch2.

For those unfamiliar with GENERATE: it is kind of a magic iteration(tests are run for every value listed without users explicitly looping over the values). If they are nested they act as a "cartesian product", i.e. this will run this test 10 times("one" 2x2 times, "two" 2x3 times).

```
TEST_CASE("Generators") {
    auto i = GENERATE(1, 2);
    SECTION("one") {
        auto j = GENERATE(-3, -2);
        REQUIRE(j < i);
    }
    SECTION("two") {
        auto k = GENERATE(4, 5, 6);
        REQUIRE(j != k);
    }
}
```

range, take, random are helpers for generation of values([docs](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/generators.md)).

Comment: Maybe look at [value-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#value-parameterized-tests).

Comment: @rustyx like I said in the question I dislike the split between values and test code.

Comment: no need for such complication, it makes test unreadable, better to thorw it and similar acrobat stuff away.